# How to include webassembly with typescript (without nodejs)

Tags: typescript, rust, webassembly

I would like to know if there is any way, as simple as possible, to include webassembly with typescript, I don't use node.
If I activate the option `allowJs: true` in `tsconfig.json` and I manually move the wasm file it works.
This solution does not seem very clean, because I have two "glue" files (network_calculator_lib.js) quite similar. Even so I tested if it could be compiled in the same folder and as I could imagine it cannot, it does not allow to overwrite the file.

I hope I have explained me good enough.
I am using Rust to compile a Webassembly with wasm-pack, although I would prefer to be able to directly import the wasm.
As a webserver I am also using one written in Rust using actix web.

Apologies and thanks in advance if I ask something very silly, but most use webpack / node and I have not found any information that clarifies me.

[image: Project tree]

Comment: The [Rust and WebAssembly book](https://rustwasm.github.io/book/) seems to already cover what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code resolve my problem:

```
import init, { exported_wasm_func } from '../pkg/network_calculator_lib.js';
async function run() {
    await init(); // You need to call init before wasm functions.
    document.body.textContent = exported_wasm_func();
}
run()
```

For people who are having similar problems:

- Compile rust with web target option: `wasm-pack build --target web`.
- In HTML, JS file or code need to be module type: `<script type="module" src="./scripts/js/index.js"></script>`.
- In Cargo.toml:

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = "0.2"
```

- Package.json is not really needed.

Source: https://aralroca.com/blog/first-steps-webassembly-rust